# Laravel 8: Update a record in database using if statement

Tags: mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-8, crud

Below is the function I used to update my record.

```html
    public function store_upd_nilai_uji_program(Request $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'nip'       => 'required|numeric|digits_between:18,18',
            'n1'        => 'nullable|numeric',
            'n2'        => 'nullable|numeric',
            'n3'        => 'nullable|numeric',
            'n4'        => 'nullable|numeric',
            'n5'        => 'nullable|numeric',
            'n6'        => 'required|numeric',
            'tanggal'   => 'required',
            'waktu'     => 'required',
        ]);

        NilaiUjiProgram::where('nim', $request->nim)->update([
            'nip'                             => $request->nip,
            'nilai_kemampuan_dasar_program'   => floatval($request->n1),
            'nilai_kecocokan_algoritma'       => floatval($request->n2),
            'nilai_penguasaan_program'        => floatval($request->n3),
            'nilai_penguasaan_ui'             => floatval($request->n4),
            'nilai_validasi_output'           => floatval($request->n5),
            'total'                           => floatval($request->n6),
            'tanggal'                         => $request->tanggal,
            'waktu'                           => $request->waktu,
        ]);

        return redirect('/prodi/daftar_nilai_uji_program')->with('status', 'Nilai berhasil diperbaharui!');
    }
```

Actually, I want to update the attribute *'nilai_kemampuan_dasar_program', 'nilai_kecocokan_algoritma','nilai_penguasaan_program','nilai_penguasaan_ui'*, and *'nilai_validasi_output'* if only the equal value in $request is NOT NULL. If the value is null, I would like to keep my record fill with *NULL*. To keep in mind that my table doesn't have any primary key. Do you have any idea how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 NilaiUjiProgram::where('nim', $request->nim)->update([
            'nip'                             => $request->nip,
            'nilai_kemampuan_dasar_program'   => $request->n1 ? floatval($request->n1) : null,
            'nilai_kecocokan_algoritma'       => $request->n2? floatval($request->n2) :null,
            'nilai_penguasaan_program'        => $request->n3 ? floatval($request->n3):null,
            'nilai_penguasaan_ui'             => $request->n4 ? floatval($request->n4) : null,
            'nilai_validasi_output'           => floatval($request->n5),
            'total'                           => floatval($request->n6),
            'tanggal'                         => $request->tanggal,
            'waktu'                           => $request->waktu,
        ]);
```

Comment: And tip for you use a clean variable name for example use $request->nilai_kemampuan_dasar_program instead of $request->n1

Comment: It works, and yes I will use your tip from now on. Thankyou very much!